# creating a weighted flow network with color and edge width in R

Tags: r, ggraph

I am trying to create a weighted flow network using some data. I would like edge width and color to represent the amount of flow between a source and a sink (rows and columns in my matrix respectively).

I used the ggraph package and tried this:

```
rm(list = ls())
#create mat
x <- matrix(c(
  0, 0.0000000, 0.0000000000, 0.000000e+00, 0.000000e+00, 0.000000e+00, 4.966243e+01, 0.000000e+00,
  0, 0.0000000, 0.0054714895, 2.787484e-04, 1.126745e-04, 2.292216e-03, 0.000000e+00, 6.007415e-05,
  0, 0.0000000, 0.0001232333, 1.292246e-06, 9.616558e-08, 9.404550e-04, 2.843154e-01, 2.752192e-07,
  0, 0.0000000, 0.0040429711, 5.605540e-05, 1.029150e-04, 1.660959e-03, 0.000000e+00, 2.543960e-02,
  0, 0.0000000, 0.0000000000, 0.000000e+00, 0.000000e+00, 0.000000e+00, 1.002884e-02, 0.000000e+00,
  0, 0.0000000, 0.0000000000, 0.000000e+00, 0.000000e+00, 7.437838e-08, 2.371584e-04, 1.496753e-04,
  0, 0.0000000, 0.0000000000, 0.000000e+00, 0.000000e+00, 0.000000e+00, 2.609883e-01, 3.370880e-05,
  0, 0.2793817, 0.0000000000, 1.002362e-02, 2.373605e-04, 2.607449e-01, 0.000000e+00, 0.000000e+00
), ncol = 8, byrow = TRUE)

#row/col names
rownames(x) <- c("phyt", "pfish", "mfish", "dfish", "bird", "seal", "ceta", "ocean")
colnames(x) <- c("landings", "pfish", "mfish", "dfish", "bird", "seal", "ceta", "ocean")

g <- graph.adjacency(x,mode = "directed",weighted = TRUE) %>%  #creates igraph object
  as_tbl_graph()

g %>% 
  activate(nodes) %>% 
  ggraph(layout = 'stress') + #imports graph
  geom_edge_hive(aes(edge_width = log(weight),color = log(weight)),show.legend = TRUE,
                 lineend = "round",
                 linejoin = "round") +
  scale_edge_color_gradient(low = "grey",
                            high = "lightgreen",
                            aesthetics = "edge_color") + #draws edges
  coord_fixed() +
  theme_graph() +
  geom_node_label(aes(label = name))
```

[image: my attempt]

Which cannot be correct. If we look at x, the value between landings and ceta is 0, so why is it showing as the largest weight on the graph? Thank you